# Display the same data and summation in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to ask and hopefully the readers can help.

this is the code i created

**Query:-**

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM rincian_order WHERE nomor_order IN ('$no_po')");
```

I have a case showing data details based on order number.
the following data.

```
nomor_order | item                        | total kg
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------
99684        | CF Rice Pandan Wangi 10 kg  | 50.0 kg
99684        | CF Rice Rojolele 10 kg      | 100.0 kg
JK14020      | CF Rice Pandan Wangi 10 kg  | 20.0 kg
```

I would like if if there is the same name it only appears 1x and its total kg increases also according to the total details per each of them, is there any solution for this?

I just use looping without any condition, do not know how.

Comment: I have edited the post I created, the variable in the IN is the order number entered, can be more than one.

Comment: I can't see `nomor_order` column in your table.

Comment: I have edited it again

Comment: I have posted my answer below, but one question: If you want to summarize the two amounts, you are gonna lose the order numbers. Is that intentional?

Comment: Well I've tried it.
It will not matter, because previously this is done to search some order number, and only show the item and the total only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this statement:

Note that I have changed your columns as they contained spaces

```
SELECT
  orders.ordernumber,
  orders.item,
  SUM(orders.totalkg) AS total
FROM orders
GROUP by orders.item
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e961c6/2/0)

The solution to this is simply grouping by the Items and adding the total kg in the end result

Comment: Oh I really do not remember the code like that, but before I've tried to group, but I so forget and messed up so I asked here.
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can use

```
UPDATE table SET total = total + <ADDED_VALUE> 
WHERE item = `<ITEM_NAME>`
```

Comment: Do you need to show the result in view level only or change the value in database? If only for view level, @Splinti's answer will do the job. But if you need to added the value in the database table, you need to do `UPDATE` query. Sorry, if I missunderstand